# MCMC sampling of tree structure

Tags: cart, bayes

I want to do Metropolis Hastings sampling of a tree structure $\mathcal{T}$ (in the space where the tree size is fixed) from a posterior distribution:

$p(\mathcal{T}|X) \propto p(X|\mathcal{T})p(\mathcal{T})$    $\qquad \qquad $  (1)

where $X$ is observed data. Suppose I can calculate the RHS easily, then the only thing I need is a proposal function. What proposal functions do people use in such kind of tree structure sampling?

Comment: Could you describe the "tree structure" in greater detail? It can be understood in different ways and so lead to misleading answers.

Comment: @Tim It's just typical tree in graph theory. You can understand it in an evolution context: the tree nodes are species. Putting the nodes together as tree in different ways give you different likelihood.

Comment: Maybe it's just not my area of expertise, but how do you define "likelihood of a tree"?

Comment: It's not likelihood of tree, but likelihood of observed data (the $p(X|\mathcal{T})$ part in equation (1) ).

Comment: But you say that different trees lead to different likelihoods so from what you are saying it sounds like it is dependent of the tree..? As you can see, it is not totally clear what do you mean...

Comment: Consider $\mathcal{T}$ as a parameter of the distribution of $X$, just like in any other Bayes problems. And I'd like to use Metropolis Hastings sampling to get a posterior distribution of this parameter. Is this more clear now?

Comment: In abstract terms yes, but still I'm not sure what kind of model you have in mind...

Comment: Does this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference_in_phylogeny) give you any insights?